# Assigning dependencies in controllers using the ES6 class syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

In a video from ng-conf 2015 ([Angular 1.3 meets Angular 2.0](https://youtu.be/pai1ZdFI2dg?t=4m41s)), the syntax for using ES6 classes as controllers is shown as:

```
class UnicornHype {
  constructor(unicornHorn, $q) {
    this.$q = $q;
    this.horn = unicornHorn
  }

  findUnicorn {
    return this.$q((resolve, reject) => {
      ...
      this.horn.thrust();
      ...
    });
  }
}
```

I see that the injected dependencies are assigned as instance properties and I'm wondering if that's a good way to do that. Since the controller's dependencies are usually singleton services, shouldn't they be shared by the instances?

The reason they've done it like this is that methods that were previously on `$scope` (and therefore in the constructor function's body) are now on the object's shared prototype. [John Papa's style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y031) actually assigns them directly to `this` (though he's not using ES6 classes - but that shouldn't really matter since they're just syntactic sugar on the constructor function `prototype` stuff). Is that a good idea?

Another approach would be to keep methods on the prototype but assign the dependencies to local variables (assuming each controller is in its own module file). Something like:

```
var q, horn;
class UnicornHype {
  constructor(unicornHorn, $q) {
    [q, horn] = [$q, unicornHorn];
  }
  findUnicorn {
    return q(...);
  }
}
```

Is this better? If yes, would `const` actually be better than `var` here? Does this approach have any drawbacks?

A third method (using `WeakMaps`) is described here: [Writing AngularJS Apps Using ES6](http://www.sitepoint.com/writing-angularjs-apps-using-es6/). Should I forget everything I said above and do it this way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why they use Weakmaps.
I quote:

> Reason behind choosing WeakMap is, the entries of WeakMap that have objects as keys are removed once the object is garbage collected.

But aren't services long-lived? So why would you need to ensure garbage collection?

In javascript all non-primitives are pointers to the original instance, so the dependencies are always shared. So why would the instance-variable approach not be a good idea?

Anyway, I think the instance-variable approach seems the most future-proof way to go.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was thinking about services in WeakMaps too.

Regarding the instance-variable approach, if you use the `controllerAs` syntax, won't this expose all your services to the view?

Comment: @spinningarrow Yes, you're right, hadn't thought about that. I think you've answered your own question.

Comment: @spinningarrow and I have hated this assign every dependency on the controller because it violates keeping scopes as small as necessary.

Comment: _"But aren't services long-lived?"_ The keys are not the services, but the controller instances.

Comment: Could discussion here, some alternative approaches that don't require assign "private" variables in the constructor. https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/issues/390