# Exposing all dependencies to view ES6 Angular

Tags: angularjs, dependencies, ecmascript-6

This question was kind of asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29262581/assigning-dependencies-in-controllers-using-the-es6-class-syntax) in one of the comments under an answer but no one seems to have commented or answered.

I just started converting some ES5 code to use ES6 javascript in one of my angular projects and noticed that when injecting dependencies, you use this syntax:

```
constructor($http, SomeService) {
    this.$http = $http;
    this.SomeService = SomeService;

}
```

What I don't understand is doesn't this expose all your services/dependencies to the view that this controller would be bound to? So your view would have access to SomeService and all its properties.

Comment: That's correct. This class isn't a controller but a *component*. And a view is *component*'s view. You can always use `_` naming convention for private variables that aren't designated to be used anywhere but the class itself (like in template).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but I'm still a little confused as to why it would be acceptable to bind all dependencies to the component itself and allow the view to access them? In es5 with angular, this isn't allowed unless you explicitly assigned it to the scope or controller instance itself. Using a naming convention can help other developers understand the scope of certain variables, but this is assuming the convention is followed strictly throughout the code base which is usually not the case. It's also misleading in that it doesn't actually designate a variable to be private.

Comment: All class members that are supposed to be private can be notated by `_` prefix, or Typescript `private`, or both. This affects the way they are documented and used by the devs. JS don't provide proper OOP encapsulation, this is language's feature that generally doesn't have to be addressed because JS isn't secure by design.  If you have a specific problem with encapsulation you're trying to solve, please specify it in the question.

Comment: And by the way, in Angular 1 OOP it becomes essentially the same - all injected dependencies should be exposed to controller `this` in order to be used anywhere but controller class constructor.

Comment: @estus _"And by the way, in Angular 1 OOP it becomes essentially the same"_ This **is** Angular 1 ^^

Comment: @zeroflagL That's a typo, I mean Angular 2. `component` concept is supposed to be a bridge between 1 an 2.